# How to implement Type switching

Tags: c#

I have a certain code snippets that needs to be executed if data-type of the variable matches to a certain base-type.Currently I'm doing this using if-else loop

ex:

```
  if(a is float)
  {
   // do something here
  }
  else if (a is int)
  {
  // do something here
  }
  else if (a is string)
  {
  // do something here
  }
```

As i have too many types against which i have to compare ,Using If else is quite clumsy . 
As C# doesn't allow type switching , Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: How about looking at the var keyword, that way the variable var would be the type that is for that object.

Comment: switch( a.getType().ToString() )

Comment: @StampedeXV seriously? I mean, no offense, but *shudder*

Comment: In general you cannot do anything else. But in some special cases some simplification can be done. What do you want to do in your code blocks?

Comment: Well, if you really want to bastardize it, you can type `a` as `dynamic`, then you can leverage Warappa's method and have the overload resolution be performed at runtime... (don't do this!)

Comment: Whenever you see yourself writing code like this, you should always ask: "what can the *dynamic* keyword do for me".  Otherwise very unclear from the question.

Comment: @PoByBolek that's why comment and not answer. It would work though.

Comment: @HansPassant: _Can_ do, or _should_ do? :)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAtIyMb6yuE

Comment: @HansPassant: Damnit Hans... now every time I see/use `dynamic`, I'm going to think of this song and dance...

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Other than performance, what's wrong with `dynamic`? I think it's fine to sacrifice some performance for expressiveness. With method overloading, the parameters are typed within each method. To get the same with if-else, you'd have to do something like `var aAsInt = a as int; if (aAsInt != null) ... else { var aAsString = a as string...` It's not very pretty.

Comment: @nmclean: Seems like a cheat to me. What if it's an unexpected type? How do you check usages of that method since there are no direct compile-time references to it? Of the options supplied in the answers/comments, it's hard to say what harin04 _should_ do since we don't have enough context. I would take the `dynamic` approach as a last-resort option though; yeah, you _could_ use it, but you _could probably_ resolve it better using polymorphic principles with compile-time safety and performance. (But who knows, maybe in harin04's case, `dynamic` really _is_ the best way to go)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Wouldn't `Action(dynamic a)` handle an unexpected type? You can't check "usages" of if-else branches either, so nothing is really lost there (actually, Resharper tells me that `Action((dynamic)o)` is a "usage" for each of the overloads, which is correct since it *could* be any of them). But it's true that this could be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @nmclean: Yeah, `Action(dynamic a)` will handle it, but essentially you're going to have a method that is `void Action(dynamic a) { throw new NotSupportedException(); }` which (imo) is kind of silly because, with this implementation, having calling code like `Action(myDynamic)` apparently _is_ supported. By "checking usages" I meant that there would be no direct compile-time references to the methods.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair The original implementation would have been a single method `Action(object)`, which *also* implies that any type is supported. Besides, maybe there is sensible default behavior for the general case. We really need to see what harin04 is actually doing. I still don't understand the "checking usages" issue... what is a scenario that would be impacted by there being no "direct" references?

Answer (score 5):

Refactor the code and use **method overloading**:

```
void SomeCode()
{
    ...
    Action(3.0f); // calls float overload
    Action("hello"); // calls string overload
    ...
}

void Action(float a)
{
    ...
}
void Action(int a)
{
    ...
}
void Action(string a)
{
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
By using the **`dynamic`** keyword (.NET 4) it works this way (full console app):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeCode();
        }

        static void SomeCode()
        {
            object o = null;
            switch (new Random().Next(0, 3))
            {
                case 0:
                    o = 3.0f;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    o = 3.0d;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    o = "hello";
                    break;
            }
            Action((dynamic)o); // notice dynamic here
        }

        static void Action(dynamic a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("object");
        }

        static void Action(float a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("float");
        }
        static void Action(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("int");
        }
        static void Action(string a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("string");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree that this is a better way of doing things, it may not be applicable if the type of `a` is not known at compile time (say it's typed as `object`)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I think it can be taken for granted that `a` is typed to `object`, as otherwise the checks shown in the question would not make any sense.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Sorry, I meant that the assumption here in this method is that the type of the object is _known_ in `SomeCode()`, but being upcasted to `object` because the signature in question is `void Action(object a)` and the question asker is just not leveraging method overloading and sharing a single method for all usage. This _may_ or _may not_ be the case. If it _is_ the case, then yes, this is definitely a good way to go. If it isn't, then this method won't help much.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Also right ;) - I introduced dynamic keyword which works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [`Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) and store the types (return values from the [`GetType` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx) of `a` along with delegates that execute whichever code you want to be run for a given type.

For example, look at this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> typeActions = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>()
{
    { typeof(int), (a) => { Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + " is an integer!"); } },
    { typeof(float), (a) => { Console.WriteLine(a.ToString() + " is a single-precision floating-point number!"); } }
};
```

This dictionary can then be used elsewhere in your code:

```
Action<object> action;
if (typeActions.TryGetValue(a.GetType(), out action)) {
    action(a);
}
```

Note that you would still have to cast `a` to the appropriate type within your actions.

EDIT: As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1269654/chris-sinclair) noted correctly, this will not recognize `a.GetType()` if `a` belongs to a subclass of a registered type. If that needs to be included, you will have to walk the type hierarchy:

```
Action<object> action = null;
for (Type t = a.GetType(); t = t.BaseType; t != null) {
    if (typeActions.TryGetValue(t, out action)) {
        break;
    }
}
if (action != null) {
    action(a);
}
```

If you need to cover generic types and/or interfaces, this is feasible, too, but the code will become steadily more complicated.

Comment: The only caveat of this is the question leverages the `is` operator which would match for derived types and interfaces as well whereas this would match exact types only. (given the question indicates `int`, `float`, `string`, this may not be an issue anyway)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Thanks, you're right - I've edited my response to cover that case.

Comment: If you like, you can also flip it and iterate the dictionary type elements and leverage [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to check for all derived types and interfaces; essentially an `is` check.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Then you would not take advantage of the hashtable lookup that takes place within the dictionary. The OP refers to "many types" - while there is no absolute number, chances are that the number of dictionary entries is longer than twice the inheritance depth of most objects `a`, so it should be somewhat faster to go by the inheritance chain rather than iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Possibly, probably. I suppose it would depend on how many types, how often this is executed, and the probability that you're passing in a derived/assignable type rather than the exact type. (If you _really_ wanted to, you could cache it. So first do a key lookup, if it fails, then iterate finding a matching type, then once you've found the type add an entry in the dictionary for the concrete type used and have it point to the same action delegate. But now, we have prioritization issues: if you have both `object` and `string` entries in the dictionary, you need to check derived types first.)

Comment: _And_ you may want to prioritize certain interfaces before others (as the `if/elseif/elseif/elseif` checks _could_ do). Ahh, it's all just one big mess. Seems all a bit pointless; I don't think we have enough context to solve the asker's problem. (Actually, I think the _real_ solution is probably to _refactor_ entirely!)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is not much different than yours but I did it like this:

```
while(true){
    var typeOfVarToCheck = a.GetType();  // a comes from Op's Code
    if(typeOfVarToCheck==typeof(type1)){
        //Do Something
        break;
    }
    if(typeOfVarToCheck==typeof(type2)){
        //Do Something
        break;
    }
    //Do default
    break;
}
```

Comment: A while loop that you prevent from looping just to avoid the else keywords ? What's the point ?

Comment: Why would you do that instead of `if` and `else`? Also, what do your conditions `type1` and `type2` look like exactly? That is what is being asked for.

Comment: Only difference is aesthetic, easier to view as it looks closer to the switch statement format (but I guess that is a subjective thing).  That is why I said it is NOT much different than the OP's solution. I will edit the post to show the type check condition

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the type into string.

```
 var typeObj = //Value...

        switch (typeObj.GetType().ToString())
        {
            case "System.Int32":
                //Some Code
            case "System.String":
                //Some Code
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: But then, how do you deal with derived types or interfaces ?

Comment: If you need to switch derived objects you´d better use a method overload. You can also implement a interface with a commom attribute, and use this inferface at classes declaration, so you can switch this attribute.